# NVD3 noData text color change

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 line chart and customize the text of noData. Now i need to update the color of the text and want text underline. I have updated the css with below changes.

```
text.nvd3.nv-noData{
    color:"yellow";
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

however, text-decoration works perfectly but color is not getting change.

I have changed fill value of svg text but it will change the text color of all the text including axis lable values.

Can someone pls help me with this ?

Comment: Have you tried `fill: "yellow"` instead of `color: "yellow"`?

Comment: Ah right, you need to use `yellow` without the quotes as pointed out by @PranavCBalan -- still for `fill` and not `color` though.

Comment: `color:yellow !important;`

Comment: fill:yellow  --> works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `fill` instead of `color` and `yellow` without quotes:

```
text.nvd3.nv-noData{
  fill: yellow;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to change the *Color* or *text* of NoData:

```
lang:
{

  noData: "My custom Text",

},
noData: {
    style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '15px',
        color: '#eeeeee'
    }
}
```